# CSS wont change text color of .cycle-pager-active in Cycle 2

Tags: css, cycle

Ive created a slider show with text pager links -

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-0">
                 <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
                    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
                    data-cycle-timeout=0
                    data-cycle-pager="#no-template-pager"
                    data-cycle-pager-template=""
                    >
                    <img src="../gray/img/s1.png">
                    <img src="../gray/img/s2.png">
                    <img src="../gray/img/s3.png">
                    <img src="../gray/img/s4.png">
                    <img src="../gray/img/s5.png">
                </div>
                <div class="pager-bg">
                <div id=no-template-pager class="cycle-pager center external ">

                    <div class="slidebtn active"><a href=#>Brand Strategy</a></div>
                    <div class="slidebtn"><a href=#>Company + Product Launches</a></div>
                    <div class="slidebtn"><a href=#>Media Relations</a></div>
                    <div class="slidebtn"><a href=#>Voicing Your Expertise</a></div>
                    <div class="slidebtn"><a href=#>Content Creation + Seeding</a></div>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

When i target the .cycle-pager-active class in css i can control everything (ie, font, font size) except the font color. Ive even tried stripping away all the css from the site and am still unable to change the color. any thoughts here?

here's the css

```
.cycle-pager-active {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-transition:background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:background .3s ease-in-out;
    height: 80px;
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: you dont have a div with class .cycle-page-active

Comment: What the answers said `.cycle-pager .active a` is how you target the active class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the link within:

```
.cycle-pager-active a{ color:#FF0000; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `.cycle-pager-active` to `.cycle-pager .active a` in css.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fxtqv433/1/

That's the strange behavior of html `<a>` tags. If you want to change the color or the text-decoration for example, you have to target the  element in css, not the parent element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder how the other answer could work because there doesn't exist an element with the class `.cycle-pager-active`. There is only a parent element `.cycle-pager` with the child element `.active`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi BlueDayz, Cycle 2 is a Jquery plugin and it generates the .cycle-pager-active class for the active button when it becomes active. So its not in the actual html but can be targeted. Hope that makes sense. But youre correct in that the <a> had to be specifically targeted